# How to get a timestamp based on a user's onclick event?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an expense tracker application and wanted to get some insight on how to **get** and **save** a user's timestamp based on when they click the submit button.

```
let timestamp = new Date().getTime();
let todate = new Date(timestamp).getDate();
let tomonth = new Date(timestamp).getMonth() + 1;
let toyear = new Date(timestamp).getFullYear();
let original_date = tomonth + "/" + todate + "/" + toyear;
```

I understand the following code grabs the current date and formats it. If I were to just populate the DOM with original_date based on a click, then it'd work with today's date, but if I check it tomorrow, then it'll grab tomorrow's date. My current problem is, how would I go about saving the date based on a user's submit event without having it update to the current time.

Idea: Would having an event listener for the button be the way to go? Let's say:

```
function addTransaction(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let saveDate = original_date;

  if (text.value.trim() === "" || amount.value.trim() === "") {
    alert("Please add a description and amount of the transaction");
  } else {
    const transaction = {
      id: generateID(),
      text: text.value,
      amount: +amount.value,
      date: saveDate
    };

    transactions.push(transaction);
    addTransactionDOM(transaction);
  }
}

function addTransactionDOM(transaction) {
  const sign = transaction.amount < 0 ? "-" : "+";

  //creating new element
  const item = document.createElement("li");

  //Add class based on value
  item.classList.add(transaction.amount < 0 ? "minus" : "plus");
  item.innerHTML = `
        ${transaction.date}
        ${transaction.text} 
        ${sign}${Math.abs(transaction.amount)} 
    `;

  list.appendChild(item);
}

form.addEventListener("submit", addTransaction);
```

Would something like this work?

Comment: Elaborate more: do you wish to save the date to the user's local storage so that when they come back at a later time, they'll see the last date when they clicked the button?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wish for the user. When they save a transaction with that date, they'll come back to a later date and see when they submitted that transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can save in the browser localStorage the data you need to be retrieved later.

For example:

```
// Store data
localStorage.setItem('originalDateKey', original_date);

// Get data
var retrievedDate = localStorage.getItem('originalDateKey');

// Remove data
localStorage.removeItem('originalDateKey');
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `window.localStorage`: [localStorage documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

`window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)` saves a string `value` to the user's local storage and can later be accessed with `window.localStorage.getItem(key)` where `key` is a unique string identifier.

Here's what I would do to achieve the desired result:

- When the page is loaded, check if we have saved a previous date to localStorage

  - If saved date found, then load it from localStorage into the DOM
- Set up a listener for the button which, saves the current date to localStorage (creating a new entry or overwriting the date that was there previously)

Here's some js flavored pseudo code:

```js
// When site fully loaded, check for saved date and load into dom
window.addEventListener("load", function (event) {
    const savedTimestamp = window.localStorage.getItem("savedDate");

    // If savedTimestamp is null, then we have no previous saved date
    if (savedTimestamp !== null) {
       // Tip: we can reuse the date object instead of
       //  creating a new one every time here
       const dateObj = new Date(savedTimestamp);
       const todate = dateObj.getDate();
       const tomonth = dateObj.getMonth() + 1;
       const toyear = dateObj.getFullYear();
       const savedDate = tomonth + "/" + todate + "/" + toyear;

       // Show the saved date, just an example
       // Put your code for showing the date here
       showSavedDate(savedDate);
    }
})

// ... rest of your code

function addTransaction(e) {
    // ... omitting for brevity
    let saveDate = original_date;
    // ... 
    transactions.push(transaction);
    addTransactionDOM(transaction);

    // Save the current timestamp to local storage
    window.localStorage.setItem("savedDate", saveDate);
}

// ... and so on
```

Make sure that `saveDate` is a string when you're saving it to localStorage, otherwise javascript will convert that to a string on its own and possibly screw things up.